# Getting row number in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ id    project_id    resource    role    start_date ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1         1           Tom       Engg    2013-09-10 ║
║ 2         1           Sam       Clerk   2013-08-23 ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Is there a way in which I can find out the row number an id, say id=2 using sql query.
Please suggest a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont really get what you want to achieve. Do you want to get the rownumber of the records when you select it? Or do you want to get the next rownumber that needs to be used?

Comment: @AnthonyClaeys Sorry for the confusion, I need to get the row number of the records when I do a select query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this::

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum + 1 as row_number, 
       t.*
FROM ( 
   < your original query goes here >
) t,
(SELECT @rownum := 0) r
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
select rownum id from your_table where your_condition
```

Comment: How to I retrieve rownum first?

Comment: @Elvin Varghese Are you trying to count no of rows for certain result?